# Bash shell scripting check while comparing 2 files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, comparison

I have 2 files

File 1

```
abc

cde

efg

hij

jkl
```

File 2

```
abc

( * ) ( * ) ( * ) -- without the braces

efg

(*) hij -- without braces

(*) (*) lmn --- without braces
```

Now, while comparing both files line by line, that is, 1st line of file1 to be compared only with 1st line of file2

```
abc ---- abc

cde ---- * * *
```

When * * * is encountered the comparison should move to next line comparing other lines

However, while comparing

```
hij --- (*) hij  or jkl --- (*) (*) lmn
```

`hij` must be compared with `hij` of File2 and must give ok
and, `jkl` must be compared with `lmn` and must given not ok : ignoring `*` or `* *` in either cases

I have written the script for the same comparing 2 files, however im unable to put the check for `*`.

Can you please help me out for the same

Snippet of the script comparing files

```
# 1. Read lines from file1 as string, and file2 as comma-separated array.

while read -r a && IFS=, read -ra b <&3; do
# 2. If both empty lines, continue.

if [[ "$a" == "" && ${#b[@]} == 0 ]]; then

    continue

fi

# 3. Start assuming diff.

diff=1

# 4. Loop fields in $b.

for e in ${b[@]}; do

    # Compare field in $b with $a, if match then abort.

    if [[ "$e" == "$a" ]]; then

        diff=0

        break

    fi

done

# 5. If no match found, print line from $b.

if [[ $diff == 1 ]]; then

    # Join array with <space>comma.

    line=$(printf ", %s" "${b[@]}")

    # Print line, excluding leading <space>comma.

    printf "%s\n" "${line:2}"

fi

# Input argument one as file 1 to stdin, and argument two as file 2 to

# file descriptor 3.

done < "$1" 3<"$2"
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? Are you saying that if any word in the line from file b (in other words, if any element of `${b[@]}`) consists of only a single asterisk (`*`), then you want to skip the entire pair of lines?

Comment: no.. if a line in file b contains a single or a double astreix ( * ) but a value later then it should be compared with file1.

However, if the line in b file contains 3 (max) ( * ) then both files should move to next line for comparison

Comment: [`Please do not repost same questions on all SO exchange`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179839/bash-shell-scripting-check-while-comparing-2-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cases of a single asterisk and a double asterisk are already being handled correctly by your script. Recall that your script assumes diff=1, and only changes to diff=0 if a match is found. The elements of `${b[@]}` that consist of exactly a single asterisk are comparing unequal to the input lines from file1, which means those elements are properly leaving the original assumption (diff=1) untouched. However, if an input line from file1 ever consisted of exactly a single asterisk, then the comparison would result in a match and set diff=0. But then the meaning of a single asterisk in file2 would become somewhat ambiguous; would it mean "match a literal single-asterisk line from file1", or would it mean "don't match any line from file1"? The latter sense seems to be what you want an asterisk in file2 to mean. If you'd want that sense to be retained in this strange case, you'd have to add an explicit test to skip an asterisk word from file2:

```
if [[ "$e" == '*' ]]; then continue; fi;
```

This test would go at the start of the `for` loop.

With regard to the triple asterisk case, it sounds like you want to skip that case entirely. As I described above, currently single-asterisk elements from file2 are implicitly skipped (because they don't match any input line from file1), which leaves diff=1, and results in the `* * *` message being printed. To prevent this, you can add an explicit guard against `* * *` as follows:

```
if [[ ${#b[@]} -eq 3 && "${b[0]}" == '*' && "${b[1]}" == '*' && "${b[2]}" == '*' ]]; then continue; fi;
```

This test would go near the start of the `while` loop, after the empty line check.

Comment: Thanks.. actually there was a mistake in understanding at my side also
so, if b[] contains ( * ) ( * ) ( * ) - 3 astreisk's
then I should skip that line in file B and compare the next line of file b with file1.
How shall i do this

Comment: Do you mean if b[] contains three asterisk then you want to skip that line in file2, but _not_ skip a line in file1, meaning you want the line numbers of the lines-to-be-compared to become out-of-sync?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the solution below; you can use a feature of bash parameter expansion to ignore leading asterisks which simplifies the script.

See bash manual, "Parameter expansion".

If you don't want the asterisks in the output, you have to assign the result of the parameter expansion used in the if statement, to a seperate variable and use this in the comparison.

```
while read -r a && IFS=, read -ra b <&3
do

    # If both lines are empty, continue.
    if [ -z "$a" ] && [ -z "$b" ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # If b contains three stars, don't compare.
    if [ "$b" == "***" ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # compare a and b ignoring leading *
    if [ "$a" == "${b##\*}" ]
    then
        echo "$a: ok"
    else
        echo "$a/$b: nok"
    fi
done < "$1" 3<"$2"
```

Besides, I would take care of removing the empty lines from the files beforehand and check for the number of lines of the two input files, to avoid mismatching errors.